# RGB to YUV improvement with ARM NEON

Tags: c, colors, arm, neon, yuv

I am trying to improve a function that converts from RGB to YUV411 for an arm device, but it's a little tricky because I have to average vectors and then the results need to be stored in an vector.

The code below shows how the function converts RGB to YUV:

```
uint8_t Y[4];
uint8_t Cb[4];
uint8_t Cr[4];
uint8_t R[4];
uint8_t G[4];
uint8_t B[4];

//basically getting R,G and B can be done in vld3_u8
R[0] = input[0];
R[1] = input[3];
R[2] = input[6];
R[3] = input[9];

G[0] = input[1];
G[1] = input[4];
G[2] = input[7];
G[3] = input[10];

B[0] = input[2];
B[1] = input[5];
B[2] = input[8];
B[3] = input[11];

// this calculation can be done in float32x4_t
Y[0]  =  0.3*(double)R[0] +  0.6*(double)G[0] +  0.1*(double)B[0];
Cb[0] = -0.2*(double)R[0] + -0.3*(double)G[0] +  0.5*(double)B[0] + 128.0;
Cr[0] =  0.5*(double)R[0] + -0.4*(double)G[0] + -0.1*(double)B[0] + 128.0;

Y[1]  =  0.3*(double)R[1] +  0.6*(double)G[1] +  0.1*(double)B[1];
Cb[1] = -0.2*(double)R[1] + -0.3*(double)G[1] +  0.5*(double)B[1] + 128.0;
Cr[1] =  0.5*(double)R[1] + -0.4*(double)G[1] + -0.1*(double)B[1] + 128.0;

Y[2]  =  0.3*(double)R[2] +  0.6*(double)G[2] +  0.1*(double)B[2];
Cb[2] = -0.2*(double)R[2] + -0.3*(double)G[2] +  0.5*(double)B[2] + 128.0;
Cr[2] =  0.5*(double)R[2] + -0.4*(double)G[2] + -0.1*(double)B[2] + 128.0;

Y[3]  =  0.3*(double)R[3] +  0.6*(double)G[3] +  0.1*(double)B[3];
Cb[3] = -0.2*(double)R[3] + -0.3*(double)G[3] +  0.5*(double)B[3] + 128.0;
Cr[3] =  0.5*(double)R[3] + -0.4*(double)G[3] + -0.1*(double)B[3] + 128.0;

// the problem is here: Cb is stored in an vector and without storing the data in the arm memory by using vst, how do I sum and average them ?
uint32_t CbAvg = ((double)(Cb[0] + Cb[1] + Cb[2] + Cb[3])) / 4.0;
uint32_t CrAvg = ((double)(Cr[0] + Cr[1] + Cr[2] + Cr[3])) / 4.0;

// next to the problem above storing in this way is a little tricky. 
output[0] = CbAvg;
output[1] = Y[0];
output[2] = Y[1];
output[3] = CrAvg;
output[4] = Y[2];
output[5] = Y[3];
```

If you have any suggestions as to how to use neon intrinsics effectively to speed up this function, please let me know.

Comment: To my knowledge NEON intrinsics use 64-bit vectors, which would only hold a single `double`.  Perhaps you would consider using `float`?  Or maybe converting your code to fixed-point integer operations.

Comment: @paddy NEON doesn't *have* `double`, only `float` without denormals (so compilers will not use it unless specifically directed to ignore ieee754 conformance).